# increase the height of search bar table view cell

Tags: objective-c, xcode

i ve got a table view were the cell height is 70.i m using a search bar..but the problem is the default table view provided by searchbar 's height not able to increase..is there any delegate method...cud u guys help me out below is the code.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (tableView == self.tableViewFriendsList) {
return 70; 
}
if (tableView == searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
    return 70;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work without problems, provided that the searchResultsDelegate is setup correctly (normally set to `self`). I just tried it with Apple`s [TableSearch](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableSearch/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code and just added

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 70.;
}
```

and the cells of both the table view and the search table view use the new height.

Comment: thanks for your effort...i ve found the answer..its actually this delegate..that worked...- (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
 willShowSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    NSLog(@"i have come to this place");
    [tableView setRowHeight:70];
   [tableView reloadData];
}